# Passing data to ViewModel when creating WPF View following MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am making a new Window-type view that I intend to show information when the app encounters an exception and I want to ti display different information for different exceptions.

Since I'm using MVVM I thought of adding a constructor in the ViewModel that takes an Exception and decides what to display based on what type the exception is.

However I am showing this new Window by using "ShowDialog" so I have no idea how to pass the exception from my MainWindow's ViewModel to that new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating a private view model instance in the child Window's code behind or XAML, just pass an appropriately initialized view model object to the Window's DataContext before calling ShowDialog:

```
var childWindow = new ChildWindow();
childWindow.DataContext = new ChildViewModel(whatever); // pass data here
childWindow.ShowDialog();
```

Or shorter:

```
var childWindow = new ChildWindow
{
    DataContext = new ChildViewModel(whatever) // pass data here
};
childWindow.ShowDialog();
```